# Angular2 Router with Site Migration

Tags: angular

I am using RC5 and `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1"` and I can't seem to catch old routes (example):

```
/category/subcategory/subcategory/articlename
```

Even with a default "pathMatch" parameter in the appRoutes. Here is a snippet of my route config:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 's/:q', component: SearchController },
  { path: ':slug', component: ArticleController },
  { path: '', component: HomeController, pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

The other routes work, its just when I try and catch them all so I can redirect them properly... Thoughts?

Comment: Your example path indicates hierarchical routing with child routes but your `appRoutes` seems to indicate only one level of routes. Actually I don't understand the question or the problem. What are "old routes"?

Comment: Old routes are from our site that we currently have up-- for example, we are moving from wordpress to a custom solution.  We want the post urls (originally /category1/category2/postslug) and now want them to just be `/articleslug`  So I would like to redirect them by having a catch all route in angular, send the request to the server and figure out what the new route is and redirect it... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch-all route would be

```
{ path: '**', component: HomeController }
```